# Assignment operator inside condition

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, assignment-operator

I found this piece of code while learning about node.js streams:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readableStream = fs.createReadStream('file.txt');
var data = '';
var chunk;

readableStream.on('readable', function() {
    while ((chunk=readableStream.read()) != null) {
        data += chunk;
    }
});

readableStream.on('end', function() {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Inside the while condition there's this `((chunk=readableStream.read()) != null)`. I understand that every statement in JavaScript returns a value, and that because of that, this piece of code works. What I can't figure out is how to replicate that code without using the assignment inside the condition.

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent loop can be made by testing the value after assigning:

```
while (true) {
    chunk = readableStream.read();
    if (chunk == null) {
        break;
    }
    data += chunk;
}
```

or you can repeat the assignment before the loop and inside the loop:

```
chunk = readableStream.read();
while (chunk != null) {
    data += chunk;
    chunk  = readableStream.read();
}
```